# how to get correct ClientID

Tags: jquery, asp.net

update:
asp.net

```
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rbl" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
    <asp:ListItem Text="None" Value="0" Selected="True" Enabled="true" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Float" Value="1" Selected="False" Enabled="true" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Float1" Value="2" Selected="False" Enabled="true" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Center" Value="3" Selected="False" Enabled="false" />
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

when i view the source this is what it is rendering:

```
$('#ctl00_ctl00_ContentMain_rbl').hover(         
    function (){
        $('#div1').dialog({title: "some title"});
        $('#div1').dialog('open');
    }
);
```

the correct clientid is: `ctl00_ctl00_ContentMain_rbl_0, ctl00_ctl00_ContentMain_rbl_1, ctl00_ctl00_ContentMain_rbl_2`

the code does not work and it did not give me the correct ClientID name when i try to read it... what is the other way round for this problem, define class name ???

```
   $('#<%= rbl.ClientID %>').hover(   
            function (){
                $('#div1').dialog({title: "Float Images Left"});
                $('#div1').dialog('open');
            }            );
```

Comment: Not really enough info here. Where is rbl.ClientID coming from? What is it's value? Do you have an element in your markup with the ID that matches what rbl.ClientID is giving? Work with us here.

Comment: Can you post the markup that it renders when you open the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how i able to achive what i wanted.

define the class to each listitem

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rbl" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
        <asp:ListItem class="rb0" Text="None" Value="0" Selected="True" Enabled="true" />
        <asp:ListItem class="rb1" Text="Float" Value="1" Selected="False" Enabled="true" />
        <asp:ListItem class="rb2" Text="Float1" Value="2" Selected="False" Enabled="true" />
        <asp:ListItem class="rb3" Text="Center" Value="3" Selected="False" Enabled="false" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the easiest way will be defining `class` to all components you want to find with jQuery.

Another way is using the [attribute ends with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/):

```
$('[id$="_rbl"]').hover( // Etc.
```

But it can cause problems if you have another `rbl` inside another container.

Remember that your items inside the RadioButtonList will be inputs, then you can do:

```
$('[id$="_rbl"] input:enabled').hover( // Etc.
```

So, if you define a class for your `RadioButtonList`:

```
$(".myclass input:enabled").hover( // Etc.
```

Comment: it does not work and i think the reason is not working is because if you look at my radiobuttonlist it has 3 list. so where exactly you want me to define the class?

Comment: When I say "define a class for your `RadioButtonList`" I means that you need to define the class on the `RadioButtonList`. The `ListItem` are generated as `input` inside it.

Comment: okay i defined the class name on radiobuttonlist and the problem is i have 3 list and if i hover over all three one by one it showing me the saame div which is incorrect, what is suppose to do is to: in which div i hover it show me the appropritate div.

Comment: Sorry, but you changed the entire question. What you want isn't regarding geting the correct `ClientID` (like your title says). It's a new question.

Comment: Sorry, the question is same as the title says and you have request met o add the html so i did, and i dont understand how is the question changed, my question is how to get a correct id.

Comment: No, your question now doesn't have nothing about the `ClientID`. About it was fully answered by me and by @mathieu. Your problem now is "how to toggle divs visibility when changing checked radio buttons". I really suggest you accepting an answer here and asking another question focusing your new problem.

Comment: @Erick: your answer is wrong when you say `When I say "define a class for your RadioButtonList" I means that you need to define the class on the RadioButtonList. The ListItem are generated as input inside it.` see my answer i able to fix - thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something on hover for the radio buttons, you have to target the inputs

```
$('#<%= rbl.ClientID %> input').hover(   
    function (){
        $('#div1').dialog({title: "Float Images Left"});
        $('#div1').dialog('open');
    }
);
```